# For every instance of a character/substring in string

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

I have a string in C++ that looks like this:

```cpp
string word = "substring"
```

I want to read through the `word` string using a `for` loop, and each time an `s` is found, print out `"S found!"`. The end result should be:

```
S found!
S found!
```

Comment: And what's your question please?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how can i accomplish the goal that is stated in the post

Comment: Did you try anything yourself? That's too broad to ask here, there are many ways to get there. Rather ask how to fix the problems with your own attempts.

Comment: i tried to use a for loop that checks to see if a char is in a string, but it didn't work

Comment: @1BL1ZZARD then please [edit] your question to show what you tried, so someone can explain why it didn't work, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could utilize **[`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void FindCharInString(const std::string &str, const char &search_ch) {
  const char search_ch_upper = toupper(search_ch, std::locale());
  for (const char &ch : str) {
    if (toupper(ch, std::locale()) == search_ch_upper) {
      std::cout << search_ch_upper << " found!\n";
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  std::string word = "substring";
  std::cout << word << '\n';
  FindCharInString(word, 's');
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
substring
S found!
S found!
```